# work with custom database data from custom tables in OpenText

Tags: php, mysql, opentext

I have a database with a table that has a column with rows with numbers 1 to X and a text.
I would like to have this read out in OT and displayed as a drop down or such so values are the numbers and the text is the displayed option.
The selected value (number) will be output in the template on the generated page (and in OT if that is possible). I want to use that number as a variable in PHP to work with it.
I think it is called "page element" in OT.

Is this possible?
How would I do this?

Comment: Which OpenText product are you talking about? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't even know they had several. I'm talking about the cms, version 10 I think. Formerly known as RedDot.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I can't help you with this product.